# What's a good Wordpress extension for coloring C/C++/script code?

Tags: c++, c, wordpress, scripting, colorize

My research group uses a Wordpress blog.  Frequently I want post snippets or even entire short programs I've been working on to it, with most of my code being written in C/C++ or scripting languages (Bash, TCL, etc).

I figure that there have to be some good extensions to Wordpress to colorify code since so many people use it.  I'm looking for something similar to StackOverflow's colorizing system, though I realize it may not be quite as robust!

Can you point me to some of your favorites/the ones you think are most reliable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the first I investigated when I started a Wordpress blog. You can use Wordpress' `sourcecode` shortcode, as exemplified [here](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/test-of-source-code-formatting/). It requires JavaScript on the client side (otherwise it renders as just preformatted text).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Nice... built in is even better! :)

Comment: That's a great find Alf!

Answer (score 2):

[GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is a good backend for highlighting lots of different languages. There are Wordpress plugins that support it, but I don't have a specific recommendation. (I use GeSHi for our wiki.)

You might also consider [Pastie](http://pastie.org) or [Gist](http://gist.github.com/) as a way to share snippets.